# How to start daemon celery worker from sh script in a dockerized environment

Tags: docker, celery, sh

I am trying to start a celery daemon worker from the entrypoint script of a docker image.

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

service rabbitmq-server restart 
rabbitmqctl add_user xxx
rabbitmqctl add_vhost sample_host 
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags xxx
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p sample_host krishna ".*" ".*" ".*" 
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags xxx administrator 
service rabbitmq-server restart  
gunicorn djsr.wsgi:application  --user www-data --bind 0.0.0.0:8020 --workers 1 --timeout 120 
celery -A djsr worker -l info -Ofair &
```

dockerfile

```
RUN chmod +x /opt/app/scripts/start.sh
# start server
EXPOSE 8020
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
ENTRYPOINT ./scripts/start.sh
```

All the commands in the entryopint script are executed, except the last one.

If I log inside the VM and start it manually it works.

```
docker exec -it cdr  sh celery -A djsr worker -l info -Ofair &
```

I have tried to add the above script in the container start file, but still not working.

I am running the docker build and the image run script from a Jenkins pipeline.

Does it have to do with the "&" at the end of the command?

I know that in production celery would need to be configured as a service, but for my application this works for now.

Comment: I would be very surprised if that were actually true. What's likely happening is that the script exits, and so does the Docker container. You can prevent this by removing the `&` from the last line.

Comment: the "&" starts it in daemon mode, so I need that  ...

Comment: I seriously doubt that; but maybe then add `wait $!` as the last line. There is usually an option to run in daemon mode without requiring the daemon to run in the background, precisely to support this type of scenario.

Comment: That script is trying to launch RabbitMQ, a Django server, and a Celery worker; those should usually be in three separate containers, all as their own container's `CMD`, and all as foreground processes.

Comment: got it, that I need to refactor it to Docker compose...

Comment: If your Docker image is not running `systemd` or another supervisor with the same API then of course these `service` commands will not work.